# Testing Reflux stores with Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, refluxjs

I'm trying to figure out how to test Reflux stores (https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) using Jasmine. Basically, the equivalent of this question, except for the fact that there is no equivalent to `runAllTimes` that I know of: [How to test Reflux actions with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463189/how-to-test-reflux-actions-with-jest)

```
it('responds to the doTheThing action and triggers afterward', function() {
  var spyFn = jasmine.createSpy('spy');
  MyStore.listen(spyFn);
  MyActions.doTheThing();
  // with Jest, I would call jest.runAllTimers() here
  expect(spyFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

^ this fails, when it should return true.

So: anyone know how to test Reflux stores using Jasmine?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by manually ticking the Jasmine clock.

`jasmine.clock().tick(jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL);`

(With calls to `jasmine.clock().install()` and `jasmine.clock().uninstall()` in the setup and teardown, respectively.)

This feels like a hack. Anyone have a better way?